# fetching null value with specify condition with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have the following data in table leave:-

```
EMPNO   NAME    DATEFROM                   DATETO
111     xxx   2014-08-03  00:00:00.000    2014-09-05  00:00:00.000
222     yyy   2014-10-03  00:00:00.000    2014-10-05  00:00:00.000
```

but when i write below query :

```
select empno,name,sum(datediff(day,DATEFROM,DATETO)+1) as holiday 
from leave 
where DATEFROM>='2014-08-01' 
   and DATETO<='2014-08-31' 
   and empno=111 
group by name ,empno
```

then I didnt get any value..but with this query i want below output:

```
 EMPNO  NAME    holiday
  111   xxx      29
```

august has 31 days..

then how can i get?

```
it will only count the day of august(08) month
```

Comment: Is UserID supposed to be EmpNo?

Comment: Are you using Chars for date columns? If they are DATE, what do you get if you remove the hyphens ('20140801')?

Comment: empno = 111 not userid = 1?

Comment: empno=111..i have edit it

Comment: @user16484..its data type is datetime... and if remove hyphens then still i'll didnt get any answer..

Comment: The query should get the desired result if `DateFrom` and `DateTo` is a `Date or DateTime` type. I think user16484 is right that the columns needs to be confirmed what type it is.

Comment: try removing the criteria from your where clause one at a time to identify which one is causing the problem

Comment: you can try using the datediff(datefromdate,querydate)>0 to figure out if the date is less than or greater than the other

Comment: i have edit the question...please take a look ..Thank you

Comment: `and DATETO<='2014-08-31'` ?? The dateTo on that empID is Sept/5.

Comment: Is Your column called "EmpNo" INT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are specifying `DateTo` MUST be `<= 2014-08-31`... but the `DateTo` value on your record is `2014-09-05`.  So that is excluding it.

I'm assuming you want all records that start in August, so you want `DateFrom` in both conditions.

Per your updates/comments:

```
declare @data table (empno int, name varchar(5), datefrom datetime, dateto datetime)
insert into @data
select 111,'xxx','2014-08-03 00:00:00.000','2014-09-05  00:00:00.000'

declare @maxdate datetime, @mindate datetime
set @mindate = '2014-08-01'
set @maxdate = '2014-08-31'

select empno,name,sum(datediff(day,DATEFROM,case when dateto > @maxdate then @maxdate else dateto end)+1) as holiday 
from @data 
where DATEFROM >=@mindate and DATEFROM <=@maxdate and empno=111 group by name ,empno
```

Per your last question regarding weekends.  What you need to do is cross join a calendar table to the event, and omit the days you don't want.  From there, instead of a `datediff()` you can simply count the remaining days.

```
declare @data table (empno int, name varchar(5), datefrom datetime, dateto datetime)
insert into @data
select 111,'xxx','2014-08-03 00:00:00.000','2014-09-05  00:00:00.000'

declare @maxdate datetime, @mindate datetime
set @mindate = '2014-08-01'
set @maxdate = '2014-08-31'

;with cal as
(
    select @mindate as dDate, datename(dw, @mindate) as DayWeek
    union all
    select dDate+1, datename(dw, dDate+1) as DayWeek
    from cal
    where dDate+1 <= @maxdate
)

select empno, name, count(*) as holiday
from @data d
cross join cal c
where c.ddate between d.datefrom and d.dateto
and c.dayweek not in ('saturday','sunday')
and DATEFROM >=@mindate and DATEFROM <=@maxdate and empno=111 
group by name ,empno
```

Comment: i have edit my question ...please see it...i want holiday from august(08) month...

Comment: Updated.  If the DateTo passes the value of `@MaxDate`, then `@MaxDate` is used, else the value of DateTo is used.  This yields 29 days in August as requested.

Comment: But if suupose i want to count weekend (sat and sunday) and remove from the holiday..now there are 29 days with weekend..but if i want to subtract 9 days(which are total weekends day from 2014-08-03.. so i want total 29-9=20 days....then how can i do that?

Comment: I have added an additional answer using a calendar CTE, then omitting Saturday/Sunday.

Comment: it is very confusing for me...is there any easy method for this??

Comment: Off the top of my head, no... not if you want it to be efficient/accurate -- and easy to maintain.  I suppose you could write a function to calculate the number of weekends and subtract that inline from your datediff(), but that isn't likely to be any easier for you.